# Calculating overtime in org tables

Tags: org-mode, formula, table

I enter my daily work hours in a spreadsheet. My daily target working time is 8 hours.
In the first line my overtime is calculated with this:

```
| Overtime |  2.5 |
|----------+------|
| Day 1    |    8 |
| Day 2    | 10.5 |
| Day 3    |    8 |
| Day 4    |    8 |
#+TBLFM: @1$2=((vsum(@<<<..@>))-((vlen(@<<<..@>))*8)
```

With integers this is no problem. But with hours:minutes it does not work anymore (note the wrong result in the first row):

```
| Overtime | 26:29 |
|----------+-------|
| Day 1    |  8:00 |
| Day 2    | 10:30 |
| Day 3    |  8:00 |
| Day 4    |  8:00 |
#+TBLFM: @1$2=((vsum(@<<<..@>))-((vlen(@<<<..@>))*8);U
```

What is wrong with my formula?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but very similar: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78256/how-to-express-time-inside-an-org-table-formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you turn on the Org Table Formula Debugger, e.g., <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-table-formula-debugger` <kbd>RET</kbd> and re-calculate the table, you see that calc actually calculates with seconds.

It is also described in the [Org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Durations-and-time-values.html) that integers count as seconds:

> Negative duration values can be manipulated as well, and integers are considered as seconds in addition and subtraction.

Also note that you miss `Day 1` with the row `@<<<`. Better use `@I` instead.

So the corrected version of your formula would be:

```
| Overtime | 02:30 |
|----------+-------|
| Day 1    |  8:00 |
| Day 2    | 10:30 |
| Day 3    |  8:00 |
| Dafy 4   |  8:00 |
#+TBLFM: @1$2=((vsum(@I..@>))-(vlen(@I..@>))*3600*8);U
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the details about integers vs. seconds. Also thanks for the hint with @I. Very appreciated!